# How Do I Get My Floppy Disks Working On Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: 16.10, floppy

I Recently found some floppy disks and an old floppy drive (3.5" 1.44MB) and decided to see if they would work in `Ubuntu 16.10`.

```
sudo mount /dev/fd0 /mnt/floppy
mount: /dev/fd0 is not a valid block device
```

How do I get my floppy disks working on Ubuntu 16.10 ?

Comment: Are you sure that the floppy drive  is / dev / fd0

Comment: Well, actually, if i cd  '/media/floppy0/'  and try and mount it that way, it will point to  '/dev/fd0/' . Sorry if i didn't give enough information earlier.

Comment: How is your floppy drive connected (IDE, USB, ...)? Can you find any messages about it in the output of `dmesg`?

Comment: It's Connected By IDE (or ATA?) and all that i could find in dmesg about floppys is this:  [    2.592118] Floppy drive(s): fd0 is 1.44M